# Get a stream from client microphone via web browser?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to implement something like voip communication that client doesn't need to install additional application, they just open the webpage and talk to a server. Is there anyway to access the audio stream from client microphone via web browser ? I don't want additional plugin like applet that user have to install.

I think flash can do this, but is there anyway else ?

Thank you,
Voteforpedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard, I think flash is your best bet.

[AS 3.0 Accessing a microphone](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000298.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your four main options are:

- Flash
- Silverlight
- ActiveX
- Unsecure browser settings (e.g. javascript calling EXEs)

All of the above will be subject to various security limitations or require some acceptance by the end-user.  I'm not even certain that the browser calling out to EXEs is even possible any more so it should be avoided at all costs.

Installing an ActiveX control will limit you to IE on Windows, so should probably be avoided. The user would have to agree to installing the ActiveX anyway.

Both Flash and Silverlight are cross-platform (Flash more so than Silverlight) but also require the user to agree to access to the Microphone/Webcam - this is done by the framework, not something you can control/influence.  Obviously, if the user does not have Flash or Silverlight installed, you'd need to prompt the user that they need to install it!

As stated by @Oded, there are serious security and privacy issues related to microphone's and webcams, so do not expect future browsers to make this easier for you (e.g. the new family of HTML5 browsers).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard that gives you access to the client machine microphone.

I can imagine there are security implication to giving a browser such access, so don't expect to see anything soon, not without some sort of plug-in.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome 11+ supports access to the microphone. Visit [this](http://www.simoens.org/Sencha-Projects/demos/) page (with Google Chrome) and click on "Speech" and try it out. This is using Sencha Ext/Touch which is an open library. This specific addon to Sencha Touch is also open source and released [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?128422-Ext.plugin.touch.CardSwipe).

Edit: To clarify, this is JavaScript only. The user doesn't need to approve anything. But, it only works in Chrome and it uses Google voice recognition.

Good luck!

Comment: This is not access to the microphone.  This is access to their speech api.  You can't get at the mic samples this way.